# Add a Text line in xml on a particular location?

Tags: c#, xml

How can I insert the following stylesheet information into my existing xml file which is created using C#?

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="_fileName.xsl"?>
```

Or.... Can I add this line at the time of creation of the new XML file?

Edit:

I tried to achieve the above using `XmlSerialier` (hit and trial), something like this:

```
// assumes 'XML' file exists.
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XElement dataElements = XElement.Load("_fileName.xml");
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parents));
var ms = new MemoryStream();
xs.Serialize(ms, parents);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // rewind stream to beginning
doc.Load(ms);
XmlProcessingInstruction pi;
string data = "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"_fileName.xsl\"";
pi = doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", data);
doc.InsertBefore(pi, doc.DocumentElement); // insert before root
doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.RemoveAll(); // remove namespaces
```

But the output xml is getting corrupted:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="_fileName.xsl"?>
<parents />
```

Whereas the desired output is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="_fileName.xsl"?>
<parents>
<parent>
<Child1>
<child2>
</parent>
</parents>
```

Did this help to understand what's my problem???

Comment: which is created using which library in c# ?

Comment: Did the above edit helps u in any way????

Answer (score 2):

You didn't answer the question.. "what lib do you use".

Although I advise:

```
XDocument
```

if you would use it you could do something like:

```
XDocument document = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));

document.Add(new XProcessingInstruction(
      "xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"_fileName.xsl\""));
//and then your actual document...
document.Add(
    new XElement("parent",
         new XElement("child1"),
         new XElement("child2")
    )
);
```

EDIT:

Ok So you could do it like:

```
 XDocument document = XDocument.Load("file");
 document.AddFirst(new XProcessingInstruction(
    "xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"LogStyle.xsl\""));
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Non white space characters cannot be added to content. in document.Add(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));

Comment: Indeed -> I spoilled it. Edited. check it now.

Comment: Thx, this is perfect for creation of new xml file, but when the file will be appended (new Child added) then this xsl information will be removed. How to retain this xsl information while appending the same xml file?

Comment: To append the existing _fileName.xml I have to first load the existing file by using XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("_fileName.xml"); statement. But afterwards the Declaration & Instructions does not work. Hence the xsl information gets removed from the existing xml file.

Comment: Once the file is created, I'm trying to add more information into the existing file. <parents> <parent1><child1><child2></parent1> <parent2>><child1><child2></parent2></parents> etc. To add more <parent> nodes into the file I was using:             XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("_fileName.xml");
            doc.Root.Add(
                new XElement("parent",
                        new XElement("child1", textBox1.Text),
                        new XElement("child2", textBox2.Text)));

Comment: see my edited answer. probably the cause why it didn't work is because you haven't added the XProcessingInstruction as FIRST! which is very important..

Comment: But I tried that already, it is not working, the updated (rewritten xml) looks like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <parents><parent1>....... I hope u r able to understand that the logic is like if(!File.Exists()) then creat(); else Append();

Comment: already? did you really do: document. **AddFirst** (new XProcessingInstruction(....

Comment: Yes, as it was not working so I was trying all other options too :P The present piece of code looks like `XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("_fileName.xml"); doc.AddFirst(new XProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"_fileName.xsl\"")); doc.Root.Add( new XElement("parent", new XElement("child1", textBox1.Text),` and go on.

Comment: I was feeling that maybe I'm asking a very naive kinda question here, I was thinking of useing `XmlSerializer` but appears as if I need to read ALOT before I can understand the real trick. :(

Comment: @ub1k I just remembered to tell u that I'm using: `System.Xml; System.Xml.Linq; and System.Xml.Serialization;` Hope I'm not forgetting anything here.....

Comment: honestly I have to tell you that I don't know what can be wrong here..  Are you now getting an exception or something? or maybe it's just the lack of xsl ProcessingInfo ? Please be precise and describe what is your problem at this point

Comment: I'm troubling u bcoz I'm so confussed, No error. The previous code (creating new xml) inserts xsl information line. When the xml file is rewritten (edited code) then the xsl information is gone. New File: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="_fileName.xsl"?> <parents> <parent> <Child1> <child2> </parent> </parents>` but when I add more information using code: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <parents> <parent1> <Child1> <child2> </parent1> <parent2> <Child1> <child2> </parent2> </parents>` Line with xsl information disappears. :(